# Avoiding copying state of a CompletableFuture

Tags: java, completable-future

I am trying to return a `CompletableFuture` that will return a response from Amazon. My code first checks to see if a response is cached locally. If so, it returns the response, otherwise it calls Amazon. [Note: The real version will also cache the response received from Amazon, but I haven't included that as the code is already pretty complicated.]

Is there a way to change the implementation of my `callAmazon` method (or otherwise reorganize the code) so that I don't have to "manually" copy the response state from `amazonApi` to the `finalResponse`?

I don't want to return `cacheCheck` directly because I don't want the caller to be able to `complete()` it.

```
public CompletableFuture<Response> fetchProductList() {
    CompletableFuture<Response> finalResponse = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<Response> cacheCheck = //...

    // First, see if we have a cached copy
    cacheCheck.whenComplete((response, throwable) -> {
        if (throwable == null) {
            // Cache hit. Return the cached response
            finalResponse.complete(response);
        } else {
            // Cache miss. Call Amazon
            callAmazon(finalResponse);
        }
    });
    return finalResponse;
}

private void callAmazon(CompletableFuture<Response> finalResponse) {
    CompletableFuture<Response> amazonApi = //...
    amazonApi.whenComplete((response, throwable) -> {
        // Copy the state to the `finalResponse`
        if (throwable == null) {
            finalResponse.complete(response);
        } else {
            finalResponse.completeExceptionally(throwable);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check out .thenCompose: http://download.java.net/lambda/b88/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose(java.util.function.Function)

Comment: Hi Alejandro, I've tried to think how `thenCompose` could be used in this situation, but I can't get my head round how it would work. I don't suppose you could sketch out some code could you?

Comment: Why do you bother about the caller calling `complete()`? Are you going to share this `CompletableFuture` between several calls? Anyway, you can easily _hide_ the method by returning a [`CompletionStage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) instead (but `toCompletableFuture()` will unhide it).

Comment: Didier, I was thinking I can use `cacheCheck.thenApply(x -> x);` to create a new `CompletableFuture` instance that I can return. The reason I don't want the caller to complete it is that I want to cache the true result from Amazon, not a result that the caller decides to put in there.

Answer (score 1):

What makes your requirement so complex is the fact that `cacheCheck` can throw an exception.

What I would do in your case is to refactor the cache to deliver either `null` if the value was not found in the cache, or the actual `Response`, if the value was in the cache.

Furthermore, I would modify `callAmazon` to return directly the `CompletableFuture`:

```
private CompletableFuture<Response> callAmazon() {
    CompletableFuture<Response> amazonApi = //...
    return amazonApi;
}
```

This way you can use [thenCompose](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-):

```
final CompletableFuture<Response> cacheCheck = //...
final CompletableFuture<Response> amazonResponse = callAmazon();

final CompletableFuture<Response> finalResult = 
        cachedResponse.thenCompose(cacheResult -> {
             return cacheResult == null ? amazonResponse : CompletableFuture.completedFuture(cacheResult);
    });
```

If you **really** need to throw an exception from the cache, you can use [exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) to convert the exception to a null value, and then use thenCompose to decide if you use the cache value, or call Amazon:

```
    final CompletableFuture<Response> finalResult = cachedResponse.exceptionally(e -> {
        return null;
    }).thenCompose(cacheResult -> {
        return cacheResult == null ? amazonResponse : CompletableFuture.completedFuture(cacheResult);
    });
```